# Bind css between <style> tag in Angular 5

Tags: html, css, angular5

I started using angular 5 and I have a problem with binding css between the tag style  from a variable in the component.ts.

So this is my code in component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  style = '.p-color{color: red;}';
}
```

and this is my html code:

```
<style>{{style}}</style>
```

Anyone have any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

One question in advance: Why do you want to do that? I don't think that's the best approach for achieving your goal.

There are several other methods in Angular 4 to apply styles:

**Class-selector**

```
<p [class.color-red]="your-expression">Your text</p>
```

**Host Binding**

```
export class SongTrack {   
  //<host class="selected"></host>   
  @HostBinding('class.selected') selected = true;
  //<host style="color: red;"></host>     
  @HostBinding('style.color') color = 'red';
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-advanced-styling-guide-v4-f0765616e635

**Set styles directly**

```
<h1 [style.color]="titleStyle ? 'green' : 'pink'">
  {{title}}
</h1>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I get a json from the backend with html, css property and i want to display it.

Comment: Normally in order to have a clear (REST) architecture you get only the data from backend in form of JSON objects. But the DOM and the CSS part will be done on frontend. I would not recommend sending HTML and CSS snippets from backend. Just adjust your styling according to your data from server with the snippets I just posted. If something is unclear, just ask :)

Answer (score 1):

create file html and css include appcomponent

```
@Component({ 
   selector:'all-page',
   templateUrl:'./code.templet.html',
   styleUrls: ['./color.component.css']


})
export class AppComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing and it worked for me

At your TS file:

```
import {ElementRef,Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   ...
})
export class Foo{

   @ViewChild('css') element:ElementRef;
   ngOnInit(){
     element.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<style type="text/css"> Your css goes here </style>';
   }
}
```

At your template:

```
<div #css>//style will be bind here</div>
```